# MVC nullable property being required at some point

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a property on my model which is a `long?`, now I have a scenario in which that property becomes required, I've tried to specify the additional view data:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ZoneId, new {
    data_val = "true",
    data_val_required = "*"
})
```

But that didnt work, which are the options I have to do this? I know how to fix this using pure javascript, but maybe there is another way im missing.

Comment: Have you considered DataAnotations?

Comment: Can you perform the validation in the action? Or is the condition of the extra validation based on some other property of the model, which means you can use IValidatableObject?

Comment: @Guillelon if I set the `[Required]` on that property it will always be required, and I need that property to be required in only one case.

Comment: @Esteban then you need a new model. That's what they are for.

Comment: @IanNewson that could work.

Comment: @Esteban yes that's why I was asking for. Bobek solution is perfect, just create a viewModel with `[Required]` for the views where you need it to be required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to use View Models in your views. That way your presentation logic does not conflict with your Domain Model.

For example, your Domain Model can stay as is, but in your View Model you decorate the property with `Required` attribute.

Comment: That would've been the best choice, but the way the application is done (wrong-way tbh) I have all my validations on the domain models, anyway, this is a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your model you decorate it with [Required] attribute.

```
public class ZoneModel
{
    [Required]
    public long? ZoneId {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: I need that property to be required in only one case, so applying that to the model won't do it.

Comment: Why can't you use a modified model in that case?